# Creating an XML file to store permissions and parsing it with PHP to create a list

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying to create an xml file to store a list of items which users within a certain role and area should be able to see, then parse this with PHP to retrieve this list.

So if a user logs in from a certain $area, that would be checked first and ignored if that area is not within the xml.

The user can only be in one $area at a time, so if the current $area matches I then need to check if their current $role matches, a user can have multiple roles.

A list should then be built of the items the user can see, with only unique items.

The XML structure looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<permissions>
    <area name="accounts">
        <role name="user">
            <item>item1</item>
            <item>item2</item>
        </role>
        <role name="manager">
            <item>item1</item>
        </role>
   </area>
   <area name="records">
        <role name="user">
            <item>item1</item>
            <item>item2</item>
        </role>
    </area>
</permissions>
```

I have started by using xpath to get the matching areas:

```
    $matchingAreas = $xml->xpath('/permissions/area[@name="' . $area . '"]');
```

Then if the $matchingAreas is >0 I'm really not sure how to proceed, my idea was to build an object using xpath items which match a list of roles:

```
foreach($roles as $role){
            $roleNodes += $matchingAreas->xpath('/permissions/area/role[@name="' . $role . '"]');
        }
```

I'm new to PHP and this is starting to seem messy/inefficient so I was hoping someone could tell me the optimal way to carry something like this out?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with a single XPath:

```
$area = "records";
$role = "user";
$itemQuery = sprintf(
    '/permissions/area[@name="%s"]/role[@name="%s"]/item', 
    $area, 
    $role
);

$permissions = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach ($permissions->xpath($itemQuery) as $item) {
    echo $item->asXML(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

will output

```
<item>item1</item>
<item>item2</item>
```

If a user can have multiple roles, you can do

```
$area = "accounts";
$role = "manager user";
$itemQuery = sprintf(
    '/permissions/area[@name="%s"]/role[contains("%s", @name)]/item',
    $area, 
    $role
);

$permissions = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach (array_unique($permissions->xpath($itemQuery)) as $item) {
    echo $item->asXML(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Due to the call to `array_unique` the output will be the same as in first example.

Comment: thanks, will I need an additional loop for each if a user has multiple roles?

Comment: @mao no, you can use a `contains` test in the XPath. See update.